# HoldAll Attributes and Delayed Evaluation: ContourPlot with solutions to NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, evaluation, scoping

This is a general question on evaluating functions that are defined to be evaluated with delay.

In particular, I am having difficulties working with the `InterpolationFunction` from `NDSolve` when I define the family of solutions as a delayed evaluation function. The end goal is to produce a contour plot dependent on different parameters in the differential equations. I provide a MWE below.

---

Take a simple system of differential equations dependent on some parameter `b` (one could use `ParametricNDSolve` also) :

```
test[b_] := NDSolve[{y''[x] - x Sin[x] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == b}, 
y, {x, -10, 10}]
```

I then define a function which is the solution of this system for a given parameter.

```
y[b_, x_] := y[x] /. test[b]
```

Since I have not chosen a parameter `b` this function **must** be a delayed evaluation function.

This function gives me no problems when I work with it. However, when I try and perform operations with graphics or symbolic functions with the attribute `HoldAll` such as `Table` or `ContourPlot` I am unable to get Mathematica to evaluate the function and give me the result. For example, with `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[y[b, x], {b, -10, 10}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

returns

```
NDSolve::dsvar: 0.0007142857142857143` cannot be used as a variable.
ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{-5.10204038248*10^-7 y[0.000714285714286]+(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0.000714285714286]==0,y[0]==0,(y^\[Prime])[0]==-9.99857142857},y,{0.000714285714286,-10,10}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
```

However, even with `Evaluate` the problem persists:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[y[b, x]], {b, -10, 10}, {x, 0, 10}]

NDSolve::ndinnt: Initial condition b is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers.
ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{-x Sin[x] y[x]+(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]==0,y[0]==0,(y^\[Prime])[0]==b},y,{x,-10,10}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
```

Similar behaviour can be observed with `Table`

```
Table[y[i, x], {i, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 10}]
Table[Evaluate[y[i, x]], {i, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

so I suspect the attribute `HoldAll` is preventing the evaluation. But somehow, the use of `Evaluate` and the delayed evaluation also prevents Mathematica from calculating a solution.

I have searched other, similar, questions in Mathematica.SE but I have not found any that reproduce the problem or provide a solution. How do I get Mathematica to work with these sorts of evaluations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error messsage actually originates from `NDSolve` and is realted to `x` being set to numeric value before the evaluation.

Workaround is to limit the scope of `x` you use in `NDSolve`:

```
test[b_] := 
   Block[{x}, 
       NDSolve[{y''[x] - x Sin[x] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == b}, 
       y, {x, -10, 10}]]
y[b_, x_] := y[x] /. test[b]
ContourPlot[y[b, x], {b, -10, 10}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Second workaround, which is slightly less nice, is to use a different name for a symbol in the plot:

```
test[b_] := 
 NDSolve[{y''[x] - x Sin[x] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == b}, 
  y, {x, -10, 10}]
y[b_, x_] := y[x] /. test[b]
ContourPlot[y[b, x2], {b, -10, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}]
```

which gives the same plot.

**Edit**

More detailes on what went wrong. From the documentation of `ContourPlot`:

> `ContourPlot` has attribute `HoldAll`, and evaluates the $f_i$
>   and $g_i$ only after assigning specific numerical values to
>   $x$ and $y$.

Let's mimic the effect of `HoldAll`, by making a function `f`, which replaces the values as does plot:

```
In[180]:= f[a_] := a /. {b -> 0, x -> 0}
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
f[y[b, x]]

During evaluation of In[180]:= NDSolve::ndinnt: Initial condition b is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers.

During evaluation of In[180]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{-x Sin[x] y[x]+(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]==0,y[0]==0,(y^\[Prime])[0]==b},y,{x,-10,10}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

During evaluation of In[180]:= NDSolve::dsvar: 0 cannot be used as a variable.

During evaluation of In[180]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0]==0,y[0]==0,(y^\[Prime])[0]==0},y,{0,-10,10}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

Out[182]= 
y[0] /. NDSolve[{(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][y][0] == 0}, y, {0, -10, 10}]
```

The probelm is that `Pattern` `f[a_]` is already solved before the numeric values are inserted and then they get inserted too agressvily.

`ParametricNDSolve` takes care of localizing the symbolic x for solving for you and for your application, it is actually [the nicesest solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181618/2036).

Comment: Why exactly do we have this behaviour? Surely, the choice of the symbols for the integration and the plotting shouldn't matter?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

For your example, using [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue) directly would be simplest:

```
yp = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {y''[x]-x Sin[x] y[x]==0, y[0]==0, y'[0]==b},
    y,
    {x, -10, 10},
    b
];

ContourPlot[yp[b][x], {b, -10, 10}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

*(The OP asks how [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue) avoids the issues in using [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed) and [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve))*

The key difference is that [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue) encapsulates the process of solving the ODE for different values of the parameter, there is no need to worry about evaluation order or conflicting arguments. When a symbolic parameter is given, the [`ParametricFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricFunction) doesn't evaluate:

```
yp[b]
```

> [image]

When a numeric argument is given, the [`ParametricFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricFunction) evaluates to an [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction) with no dependence on the ODE independent variable:

```
yp[1]
FreeQ[yp[1], x]
```

> [image]
>
> True

Here are some variations on using a ParametricFunction:

```
yp[b][x]
yp[b][1]
yp[1][x]
yp[1][1]
```

> [image]
>
> 1.04674

Unlike the OP approach, no errors occur for any of the above inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Why does `ParametricNDSolve` work and how does it avoid the problems @Johu mentions in his answer? I didn't think the difference would be so large between a delayed evaluatin `NDSolve` and `ParametricNDSolve`.