# Huge time to plot a function with replace all (/.)

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am looking to  plot the function `f[x, y]`

```
  f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Cos[x + y]/Sqrt[1 - y^2]
```

where `y[x]<1` is the solution of the equation

```
y[x_] := y /. FindRoot[1 + int[x, y] + D[int[x, y], y] == 0, {y, 0.8}]
```

and where `int` is the numerical integral

```
int[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[-x/Sqrt[1 - t^2]]/(t^2 - y^2), {t, 0, y, 1}, Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
```

- First, if I try to calculate the derivative `D[int[x, y], y]]` at `x = 50` and `y = 0.8`

  ```
  Block[{x = 50, y = 0.8}, D[int[x, y], y]]
  ```

I get the error

```
(*\[PartialD](-5.391169080810072`*^-23)/\[PartialD]0.8`*)
```

> General::ivar: 0.8` is not a valid variable.

- Second (my real problem), when I plot this function for `0<x<10` by *replace all* command

  ```
  Plot[f[x, y]/.y -> y[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, PlotRange ->{-3, 3}]]
  ```

it takes a huge time.

Thanks in advance for the answers and suggestions.

Comment: You're reusing the symbol `y` in a lot of different ways in these 4 lines. There's a reason it's known as good practice to use unique & descriptive function/variable names. I think doing so in this scenario might help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to limit the scope of `y` in `y[x_] := y /. FindRoot[1 + int[x, y] + D[int[x, y], y] == 0, {y, 0.8}].`

I will adapt [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181611/2036) to your problem.

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Cos[x + y]/Sqrt[1 - y^2]
ClearAll[y]
y[x_] := Module[{y}, 
   y /. FindRoot[
     1 + int[x, y] + Evaluate[D[int[x, y], y]] == 0, {y, 0.8}]];
int[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Exp[-x/Sqrt[1 - t^2]]/(t^2 - y^2), {t, 0, y, 1}, 
  Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
Block[{x = 50, y = 0.8}, Evaluate[D[int[x, y], y]]]
```

> 1.39305*10^-22

Your real problem seems to be, that the integral does not converge. I cannot even evaluate `int[10, 0.8]`, as I get warning messages:

> `NIntegrate::zeroregion: Integration region {{0.8,0.800000000000000044408920985011711129445345555642315378316693834590}} cannot be further subdivided at the specified working precision. NIntegrate assumes zero integral there and on any further indivisible regions.

I do not think these messages should be ignored and there is a reasonable precision limit one should use. Before increasing precision, I would rethink possibility of analytical simplification.

Comment: Thank you @Johu, it's a nice analysis. For me the integral converge: `int[10, 0.8]=-0.000029950778`. What's the problem for you?

Comment: What's about the huge time in plotting this function?

Comment: One cannot plot it if it cannot be evaluated.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about this huge time?